# Eclipse not allowing me to make an android project [Ubuntu]

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu, adt

Im runnning Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Eclipse Platform Version: 3.8.1

**[Back-Story]**

I've been using Ubuntu on this Laptop since version 13.04 and have been making android apps without problem ever since, then when I updated to Ubuntu 14.04 (from 13.10) Eclipse Hung on the start-up at "Loading Workbench" to which a solution on the site was run it as:

```
eclipse -clean
```

This made Eclipse start up again without problem, but now Android tools and ADT was missing. I tried reinstalling it, and this is where my problem really begins.

**[Problem]**

After reinstalling the ADT plugin from Google and restarting (as well as re-importing my workspace) Android does not appear as an option for a new project. There is also no SDk button or Android Virtual Machine button in the interface. I've looked high and low for answers but havent came across anyone with this problem. Ive tried reinstalling, purging, woving workspaces, restarting eclipse, but nothing worked.

Is there some way to re-enable it?

Comment: `Android Tools` are not bundled with eclipse, you will need to install it as well

Comment: Please follow the instructions given at [Installing the Eclipse Plugin](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) and post your results.

Comment: I already did that hence me saying "reinstalling the ADt plugin". Its not working and thats what I need help with.